# Comcast gave my social security number to a collection agency.

Tags: privacy, business

Comcast thought I was in default on my cable/internet account. I kept telling them they were wrong, and I had proof, but they refused to listen until I got the Attorney General involved. They finally admitted it was a computer error, and eliminated the debt and called off the collection agency. My concern is that they provided my ssn to someone who I have no contact with, and no idea who they are or where they are located. This collection agency called me prior to Comcast correcting their records. When I refused to give the collection agency any information, they made a point of telling me they had my social security number. I took that statement as a threat that they would do something. Do I have any action I can take against Comcast for giving out my ssn?

Comment: What country (and if in the US, state) do you reside in?

Comment: Also, concerning "they made a point of telling me they had my social security number. I took that statement as a threat that they would do something". This may be a legal threat. Debt collectors can and do sue to collect on debts, as well as they can sometimes gain liens and wage garnishment orders.

Answer (score 3):

There might be some relevant state law. Michigan has a [Social Security Number Privacy Act](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(ksb1rk1pmddu3qvx1rgi0332))/mileg.aspx?page=getObject&objectName=mcl-Act-454-of-2004), which limits use of SS numbers, such as publically displaying an amount of a number, use it as an account number, require it to be transmitted insecurely over the internet, mail it etc. However, it *is* allowed under 3(a) to mail a number in a document if the purpose is to identify an individual, especially 3(a)(iv), to

> Lawfully pursue or enforce a person's legal rights, including, but not
>   limited to, an audit, collection, investigation, or transfer of a tax,
>   employee benefit, debt, claim, receivable, or account or an interest
>   in a receivable or account.

It would depends on your state, but it is highly likely that debt collection is an allowed purpose (even if it not a real debt, just a good-faith mistake). [This](http://consumersunion.org/news/state-laws-restricting-private-use-of-social-security-numbers/) gives a brief overview of state laws.